# How to GROUP BY a foreign key in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working in BigQuery. I have three tables: branches, regions (which are collections of branches) and spending by branch by month.

```
CREATE TABLE region (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE branch (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar NOT NULL,
    region integer NOT NULL 
);
CREATE TABLE spend (
   branch integer NOT NULL
   amount float,
   month timestamp,
   item_code int
);
```

How can I get total spending by *region* by month?

I've got this for total spending by branch by month:

```
SELECT branch, 
       month, 
       SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM [mytable]
GROUP BY branch, 
         month
```

But I don't know how to group this up by region. I think I need an `IN` clause somewhere?

It's quite a big dataset too (150GB/500m rows in the `spend` table) so large JOINs may not work.

Comment: You say you have 3 tables, but you select from a 4:th...

Comment: Sorry, it should be `FROM spend` - it's just that the BQ syntax is slightly different (`FROM [mydataset.spend]`).

Comment: For what it's worth, BQ excels at joins, especially between a large table and a small/medium one (but even large/large should work fine). I'd just give it a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a join and aggregation, which I'm pretty sure that Bigquery supports:

```
SELECT b.region, s.month,  SUM(s.amount) AS total_amount
FROM spend s join
     branch b
     ON s.branch = b.id
GROUP BY b.region, s.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.name as region, [month], SUM(total_amount) AS total_amount 
FROM (
  SELECT branch, [month], SUM(amount) AS total_amount
  FROM [mydataset.spend]
  GROUP EACH BY branch, [month]
) AS s
JOIN [mydataset.branch] AS b ON s.branch = b.id
JOIN [mydataset.region] AS r ON b.region = r.id
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

GROUP EACH BY and pre-grouping in sub-select is used here to address your concern: `large JOINs may not work`.